# How can one construct an object from a parameter pack in a C++ template?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, parameter-pack

Given the following, how can I correctly construct an object of an unknown type from a parameter pack?

```
template < typename... Types >
auto foo( Types&&... types ) {
    auto result =  Types{ }; // How should this be done?
    // Do stuff with result
    return result;
}
```

I expect the template function to only be called with matching types, so everything in the parameter pack should be of the same type. It doesn't matter which individual item I reference if I need to use `decltype`, for example (relevant code in the commented out section will cause compilation errors otherwise).

Comment: And if the parameter pack is empty, what object do you expect to be created? An `int`? A `bool`?. And if the function requires at least one parameter, just declare a function with one template parameter and a possibly empty parameter pack, and just use the first parameter's type, directly.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik easy fix ```static_assert( sizeof...( pack ) > 1 );```. Also I had considered that possibility but lets ignore it for now and just answer the question as is. Assume use in another scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all the types in the parameter pack are the same, you can first use the comma operator to expand the parameter pack, then use `decltype` to get the type of the last operand.

```
template<typename... Types>
auto foo(Types&&... types) {
  auto result = decltype((Types{}, ...)){ };
  // Do stuff with result
  return result;
}
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/59xs547MY)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way (assuming we are talking about relatively simple types, which can sustain copying):

```
template < typename... Types >
auto foo( Types&&... types ) {
    return std::array{types...}[0];
}
```

Here is another, more convoluted, but working way, which puts no additional limitation on types:

```
#include <tuple>

template < typename... Types >
auto foo( Types&&... types ) {
    using tup_t = std::tuple<Types...>;
    auto result =  std::tuple_element_t<0, tup_t>{}; 

    // Do stuff with result
    return result;
}


// auto k = foo(); // compile error

auto z = foo(10); // z is 0-initialized int
```

Comment: An interesting work around, may have to go with that if no one else comes up with a more direct solution. Thanks!

Comment: @cbrng added one more

Answer (score 0):

Since all the types in the parameter pack are the same, you can use [std::common_type_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type), which gives a type that all the types in the parameter pack can be converted to.

```
template <typename... Types>
auto foo(Types&&... types) {
    auto result = std::common_type_t<Types...>{};
    // Do stuff with result
    return result;
}
```